# InputLayout handling

Tags: models, directx11, directx10

Where are you supposed to store InputLayout?

Suppose i have some basic structure like.

```
class Mesh
{
   List<MeshPart> MeshParts
}

class MeshPart
{
   Effect Effect;
   VertexBufferBinding VertexBuffer;
   ...
}
```

Where should I store input layout?

It's a connection between vertex buffer and specific pass, i can live with just 1 pass but I still have diffferent techniques so i need at least an array with some connection to effecttechniques, but I would appreciate something not crazy like dictionary. I could also create wrapper for Effect and EffectTechnique, but there must be some normal solution.

Comment: See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25384/how-best-to-handle-id3d11inputlayout-in-rendering-code/47987