# Retrieving shader byte code using D3D11

Tags: c++, directx, directx11

I have a shader as an 'ID3D11VertexShader' (or generally any 'ID3D11*Shader') instance. For my application I would like to read the shader byte code that is associated with this instance.

The goal is the create an `D3D11InputLayout` without having to carry around the byte code blob.

Is there a way in DirectX 11 to retrieve the byte code, that was used to create this shader? I was looking for something similar to `glGetProgramBinary` (that would return the byte code instead of the binary code).

Comment: Why would DirectX retain this bytecode after compiling the shader?

Comment: Related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25384/how-best-to-handle-id3d11inputlayout-in-rendering-code

Comment: The 2nd sentence says it all, you want to get the input layout.   If you have the shader, have you looked at Shaderreflection -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11shader/nn-d3d11shader-id3d11shaderreflection.  Sounds like you have the shader instance, this I believe will give you back the fields, offsets etc.